# PHP Session Variable - change on page load

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to get a session variable to alternate between 0 and 1 on each page load.

So first time page loads

```
$_SESSION['turn'] = 0;
```

Second time

```
$_SESSION['turn'] = 1;
```

Third time

```
`$_SESSION['turn'] = 0;`
```

and so on.

Then I can call that variable later in the page.

I can't work out how to do this.  I've tried a simple IF function but can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this where the page is loaded.

```
$_SESSION['turn']=1-$_SESSION['turn'];
```

code:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['turn'];
$_SESSION['turn']=1-$_SESSION['turn'];
?>
```

Edit : RiggsFolly !isset() is correct. mine misses it and it will give errors in log. and the first value is not 0

Comment: This will error the first time it is run for a visitor as the `turn` key will not exist.

Answer (score 1):

First the session must be started on any page wishing to make use of the session array. `session_start()`

Next you have to remember that initially the session variable you are using will not exist the first time you attempt to use it

So

```
<?php
session_start();

if ( !isset($_SESSION['turn']) ) {
    // does not exist yet, so create with 0
    // you may want to initialize it to 1, thats up to you
    $_SESSION['turn'] = 0;
} else {
    $_SESSION['turn'] = $_SESSION['turn'] == 0 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!